# malloc returns null when run with Valgrind

Tags: c++, c, linux, memory-management, valgrind

I have a huge allocation (tens of GBs) happening with a malloc call which works in normal scenario. The system does have a huge RAM and is a 64 bit machine running 2.6 x86_64 kernel.

The mem rlimit has been done as INFINITY with setrlimit.

I thought of running it with Valgrind to do the memory analysis and check for the leaks.

But malloc fails with NULL pointer returned when run with valgrind.

I tried reducing the size of allocation but that doesn't help.

Any inputs ?

Regards,
-J

Comment: Valgrind uses a lot of VM to keep track of the rest of your VM.

Comment: How much RAM does this system have? How many tens of GBs?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that `malloc(3)` is lying to you -- it doesn't actually allocate all the memory at once, it just asks the OS for it, and the OS lies to `malloc(3)`. This is perfectly normal behavior that most of the time works fine. The description for `/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory` in `proc(5)` contains the details:

```
   /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory
          This file contains the kernel virtual memory
          accounting mode.  Values are:

                 0: heuristic overcommit (this is the default)
                 1: always overcommit, never check
                 2: always check, never overcommit

          In mode 0, calls of mmap(2) with MAP_NORESERVE are not
          checked, and the default check is very weak, leading
          to the risk of getting a process "OOM-killed".  Under
          Linux 2.4 any nonzero value implies mode 1.  In mode 2
          (available since Linux 2.6), the total virtual address
          space on the system is limited to (SS + RAM*(r/100)),
          where SS is the size of the swap space, and RAM is the
          size of the physical memory, and r is the contents of
          the file /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_ratio.
```

Valgrind cannot be so flippant; it actually keeps track of allocated, initialized, and uninitialized memory for a process. It therefore requires *more* memory than the process does on its own, and it does not have the same tolerance for over-committing memory.

I do not know how much more memory you will need to run the program under valgrind, but try adding a few more gigabytes of swap space. You can make a new swap *file* by using `dd` to write zeros to a file -- do not use a sparse file -- and then run `mkswap(8)` on the file to initialize it and run `swapon(8)` with the filename to tell the system to use it as a swap file.

Comment: the vm/overcommit_memory is set to 2 which means it will never overcommit. I should probably do a test by setting it to 1. and overcommit_ratio is 110 .

Comment: I don't think this is the issue. Rather, valgrind requires a LOT of memory to track/debug all the memory you use. If I remember correctly, for some types of allocations it even duplicates them for its own tracking use, so allocating 10gb could actually require 20gb...

Comment: @R..: depending on the checks runs, but yes, `memcheck` actually duplicates the memory because it tracks writes at the *bit* level.